# How to filter specific IP address in android using netfilter?

Tags: android, netfilter

I want to develop an android app which filters out specific IP address so that next time it wont connect to that IP. But recently I found that in the web that there is certain API called Whispercore API which enables the netfilter functionality in android? Can any one help how to program using the API?